# MERN Stack quicker API calls

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I've been wondering what techniques do you guys use to speed up your applications' API calls.
I've made an application, which has loads of images (saved in MongoDB as binary data) and when I make the GET request to the server it takes a good few seconds (like 5 to 10 seconds) to load the documents and the respective images. 
I would love to speed up the API calls and the server responses if there's a way, but all tutorials online that I found are pretty irrelevant or outdated.

Please, anyone who uses the MERN stack, can you share your magic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to analyze your application to figure out where the time is being spent, then address the specific issues identified. There is no one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly build my own stack (but same as mpst developer) by checking all features one-by-one.

DB : Sometimes MySQL or MongoDB
NodeJS backend : mysql/mongoose with expressJS and axios if necessary by using axios on frontend.
Front-end : ReactJS with fetch but can be used with axios

And my recipe app is very fast when fetching something :) (1sec max for checking all the DB)

Have fun